# Java Method overriding in same class

Tags: java, variables, methods, overriding

In the same class i have 2 methods.

```
    private boolean check(){
          String User = "none";
          boolean checker = false;

           //some code that might change checker variable

          if (User.equals("Admin"))
                 checker = true
          return checker               
    }
```

and

```
private void setUser(){
       check(){
            User = "Admin"
       }
       //code that will set the User
}
```

This gives me compile errors. It seems i can't override methods like this in java. Is there any other way for me to do this? I just need to run the `check` method inside the `setUser` method after setting its `User` variable. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then the short answer is no. You can't override a method locally to provide a local variable. I suggest you modify your approach slightly. First, pass the `user` to `check` and make `check` a static function (and I don't recommend keeping a `boolean` flag to return; just `return`) like -

```
private static boolean check(String user) {
  return user.equals("Admin");
}
```

Then, you should probably make `setUser` also take a `String` and it I think you meant for it to be `public` and I think you want `isAdmin` field. Something like

```
private boolean isAdmin = false;
public void setUser(String user) {
   if (check(user)) {
     this.isAdmin = true;
   }
   this.user = user;
}
```

Finally, Java variables start with a lowercase letter by convention.